# Javascript files are being loaded automatically into Grails app

Tags: javascript, grails

I'm using Grails 3+. I have a folder in my app `grails-app/assets/javascripts`. Any js file I put in here loads automatically.

I have a GSP file with this tag `<asset:javascript src="application.js" />`. This tag loads a file that is in the `grails-app/assets/javascripts`. So basically the same file is being loaded twice.

My question is this. Why does Grails automatically load the JS files in the javascripts folder? How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: `ApplicationResources` is used by the resources plugin which is abandoned and doesn't have a version for Grails 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `application.js` probably includes the line

```
//= require_tree .
```

which includes all files in the current directory and subdirectories. Check out the [asset-pipeline plugin docs](http://www.asset-pipeline.com/manual/) for more info about the syntax for manifest files.

Comment: wow, i totally glossed over this. I didn't know that grails processed comments.